# Migrate Content to Azure

Tags: azure, migration

I have installed a baseline 8.2.7 Sitecore to Azure using the XP templates in the Azure ToolKit.

How to I get my existing content into the databases ?

If I try to import a bacpac file I get a new database.

If I delete the master and import my bacpac to a new master I get an error in the content editor that it can't login as cmmmasteruser

So the install created that login and gave it a password that the content editor knows ?

Any way to fix this ?

Or is there some other way to move the content ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I delete the master and import my bacpac to a new master I get an error in the content editor that it can't login as cmmmasteruser

You need to either create the new contained database user or update the existing user's password. Eg.

```
ALTER USER masteruser WITH PASSWORD = 'password';
```

You can find the password in your CM connection strings.

Another option is to use a tool such as [Razl](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl) or [Sitecore Sidekick](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Sidekick.aspx) to sync content items between environments.